# How to properly use the AngularJS digest cycle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest

I've been looking into the caveats of the AngularJS Digest cycle and I would like to better understand where the separation is between using it properly and improperly.

For example, if I have an AngularJS code that looks like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module("testApp", []);

myApp.controller("testController", ["$scope", "$timeout", function($scope, $timeout){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $scope.username = "Test User name";
    }, 3000);

    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.username = "AngularJS User name";
    }, 3000);
}]);
```

Why is `setTimeout` not being used as part of the Digest Cycle, whereas `$timeout` is, and how can I fix this to work?

*Please keep in mind*, I am looking not only for a code solution but for **an explanation** of why this occurs. As good as a code solution may come, it will **not explain itself**.

Comment: setTimeout isn't part of angular and therefore doesn't trigger change detection. The solution for that is $timeout, what's left to explain?

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz I just don't understand why that would be, when AngularJS typically wraps your code in a `$scope.$watch` function, yet despite that it does not look within `setTimeout`.

Comment: `setTimeout` is just a plain javascript function so angular cannot $watch it.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz is this the case for all other plain javascript functions as well? Meaning if I meant to use one with the digest cycle, I must ensure that AngularJS knows about them?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it's a common mistake for people coming from jQuery to wonder why changes aren't detected when they call jQuery functions.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz ok that's starting to sink in, thanks for the info!

Comment: Absolutely no problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$timeout` is an angularized version of `setTimeout()`, i.e. it is coded in such a way that it triggers a digest cycle. `setTimeout()` is a plain Javascript function that knows nothing about Angular or a digest cycle. Since `setTimeout()` is not a simple JS object, Angular cannot `$watch` it.

So the whole point of having functionality like `$timeout` is that they are angular-friendly versions of some Javascript functionality.

Comment: Interesting, so any other functions that are native to javascript and have not been *angularized* will also be subject to such? Meaning I should be looking for the service version of it and expect it to work in the *angular way*?

Comment: Typically, other JS functions are free of effects that would trigger a digest cycle. DOM manipulation functions would be different, that's why you should not use JS or native DOM manipulation but leave that to Angular and its templating (which of course knows about the digest cycle) or use the angularized `angular.element` methods. Things like array manipulation which change the model and therefore should trigger a digest are taken care of by the `$watch` functionality built into Angular that guards properties of the `$scope` object

Comment: Ok so plain JavaScript functions in general, used within AngularJS, are only safe to use for scope or DOM manipulation as long as they are in line with what AngularJS is doing on top of them. I get it now.

Comment: That's the general idea, yes.

Answer (score 1):

`$timeout()` and `setTimeout()` are not the same, $timeout is *angularised*.

It uses promise ($q service) internally, which would resolve after every digest cycle, automatically. Whereas `setTimeout()`, is just a trick with registering your callback function in the queue.

If you want setTimeout() to be part of digest loop, call it within the $scope.$apply():

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.username = "Test User name";
    });
}, 3000));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I modified your answer to correctly use`$scope.$apply`

Answer (score 1):

A more generic explanation is that `setTimeout` does not work inside of angular because it puts its callback on the event loop, which angular does not watch. The same situation would happen if you were to create an `XMLHttpRequest` directly instead of `$http`.

Angular has made their own abstraction of these utilities/objects so that when they finish, the digest cycle will pick up any changes.

Comment: That's a **better** version of a generic explanation, especially when considering the AngularJS digest cycle vs the JavaScript native event loop, big difference yet invisible to the naked eye

Comment: @AGE better enough that I get the green check? :)